# Telnetting into Emulator using Android Studio vs Telnetting into Telnet Server running inside Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, telnet

I have been learning to code in Android (once again), using Coursera. Our instructor has asked us to `telnet` into our emulator using `telnet localhost 5555` through `Android Studio` terminal, which works fine for me as well, and I can use all the commands like,

```
network speed edge
network speed full
power capacity 10
```

Which is totally ok. 
But after that, what I did is, I installed `Telnet Server` app in my Emulator through an `apk` file, created a telnet server in my Emulator, Connected to the telnet server through my host pc, and then tried executing the same commands as above. But the above commands i.e `power capacity 10`, `network speed full`  doesn't work this time.

I do not understand what is the difference between a telnet connection when connected through `Android Studio` terminal, and when connecting to the telnet server created inside the Emulator.

Why can't I run the same commands when I connect to my emulator's telnet server ?

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"?  Please be specific.

Comment: Hi Dough. I have added the details. 
I want to know why I can't run commands like `power capacity 10` or `network speed full`, when I am connected to the Telnet Server, created through an app inside my emulator.
for instance, if i type `network speed full`, it simply says `sh: network: not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The telnet connection to the emulator over port 5555 is a special type of connection where you can issue [commands that affect the operation of the emulator itself](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).

The Telnet Server app doesn't have this kind of special connection.  Instead, it's just giving you access to a linux command shell that will execute other linux command line programs that you issue, similar to the command line interface on your computer.

Basically, they are two very different things and not related at all except for their use of the telnet protocol to send text back and forth.

Comment: That's what I was talking about. So, there is no way to  connect to that *special* kind of telnet session through a Telnet Server, where we can issue commands that affect the operation of the emulator itself ?

Comment: No, the port 5555 connection is handled by the emulator process as it runs on your local machine.  There isn't a way to get a hold of that from within an app such as Telnet Server.  That would actually be a pretty big security hole.

Answer (score 0):

write `auth ?` after conect telnet to get link to file emulator_console_auth_token*. copy code in file and write `auth codeinfile` .
done.